# using stream.pipe make express middleware skipped

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im using `express` and `nodejs` for my api server,
and now im implementing pdf download (im using `pdf-creator-node`) for converting html to pdf.

the `pdf-creator-node` will create a stream when converting a html, and when i pipe it, all my middleware (`notFoundHandler`, `errorHandler`,`responseLogger`) got skipped

```
router.get(
  '/generatePDF', authenticate, schemaValidation({ params: generatePDFschema }),
  (req, res, next) => {
generatePDF(details) {
      const template = readFile('./src/templates/da-template.html');
      const receipt = {
        html: template,
        data: payload,
        type: 'stream'
      };
      const generatedPdf = pdf.create(receipt, advisOptions);
      return generatedPdf;
    }

    const pdfStream = generatePDF(details);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    pdfStream.pipe(res);
},
notFoundHandler,
errorHandler,
responseLogger
);
```

is there any express api can i use to pipe a stream?

Comment: Can you show more context for this code?  It's not clear where this code resides.  Is this client code and this is an upload?  Is this code on your server showhow?  And, what exact middleware is being skipped that you want to be doing something?  Please show a lot more context so we can better understand what you are doing.

Comment: this code i take from my handler inside a `router.get()`, i have 3 middleware which should be running, 2 of em is errorboundary middleware, and 1 is for counting response time for each request

Comment: added more on code block, hope this add more context to my quest

Comment: This code looks incomplete because there isn't even a `res` defined in the request handler arguments.  Please show us your REAL code, not some reduced version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The middleware you show is passed to `router.get()` AFTER your request handler so it will not get a chance to run unless you call `next()` in your request handler.  When you pass multiple request handlers to a `router.get()`, they will run sequentially in order and the 2nd one will only get a chance to run if the first one calls `next()`.  Same for the 3rd one, and so on.

Furthermore, `pdfStream.pipe(res);` does not call `next()`.

I don't know exactly what those middleware functions are supposed to do, but making a guess based on their names, perhaps they are supposed to run BEFORE your request handler, not after so they can put things in place for various error conditions.

If you want further help, then please show the code for those three middleware functions so we can see more specifically what they are trying to do.

Comment: i have tried to add next after `pdfStream.pipe(res);` yes it called my other middleware, but will get 500 and it says "Failed to load PDF file." on postman

Comment: @tiwtiwtiwtiwaaaaa - Yeah, there's no way you should be calling `next()` BEFORE the `.pipe()` finishes (remember, it's asynchronous).  And, you should probably not be calling it at all.  I can't help you further until I can see the code for those three middleware functions to see exactly what you want them to do.  Probably, they should NOT be after your main handler.  But, I can't make any concrete recommendation without seeing their code.